# Display only child items in Expandable list No need of parent indicator

Tags: android

Hi i am displaying items according to different categories using Expandable Listview.Now I want to display only items ,No need of parent name or parent indicator.is there any solution from expandable list view to diplay only child items .I don't have time Thats y i am displaying items from expandable list view(I am alredy developed this one) .So please give me some suggestions.It is very urgent.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot have child view without group view in ExpandableListView. Which adapter you are using for populating group and child view?

Comment: I am using ExpandableListAdapter.

Comment: In ExpandableListAdapter, u need to implement getGroupView method, and getChildView method. In getChildView method, u need a groupposition for populating childview. hence i think that without populating groupview, childview cannot be rendered

Answer (score 0):

You should use lisview instead which is easy to used.